# How to access the port that Kestrel web server is listening on inside .NET Core HealthCheck class

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have recently started to implement .NET Core HealthChecks into by Web API project. The port that Kestrel should listen on is currently configured by the Linux service that runs the app (so it is passed through to the Startup class using the --server.urls command line parameter) ie

`ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /api/dev/MyApi.Web.dll --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5001`

I have written a healthcheck that checks various endpoints that the API exposes and ensures that they are returning an HTTP 200 OK result.

I need to be able to access the port that kestrel is listening on so that I can fire off web requests to each endpoint ie `http://localhost:{port}/endpoint`. Does anybody know of a way to achieve this or am I better off just storing the port that Kestrel should listen on in `appsettings.json` and accessing it via `IConfiguration`?

Comment: You shouldn't do that on runtime. The port on which kestrel is meaningless in most cases. When it runs in Docker, it would be only the internal port and not the one exposed outside, when running behind a reverse proxy (nginx, IIS), the requests will use the port exposed by the proxy. Its a pretty unreliable source of information

Comment: Hi Tseng, thanks. I would agree IF I was firing web request out and back in again, but  if I'm sending them to localhost I'd need the port number wouldn't I?

Comment: That wouldn't be true in case you use docker, since the exposed port would be the one reachable from the docker host and not the internal port within container will break, when change your hosting (i.e. docker or reverse proxy). Anyways the server.urls should be accessible via `Configuration["server:urls"]` if you the `AddCommandLine` configuration is included (which is by default unless you Opt-out from using `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` and not add it then)

Comment: Fair point. I'm not even sure that testing endpoint response codes in the application itself is even the right thing to do so might end up binning this altogether. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Also remember, that the value passed to `--server.urls` may not be the value actually used (IIS Middleware may set a different port, of course only when hosted in IIS)